# GR_jll keeps failing to precompile where using Julia 1.6.0 RC1 on Windows

Tags: julia

I use Julia 1.6.0 RC1 and all packages work great except for `GR_jll` that keeps failing to precompile.
In result also `Plots.jl` does not get precompiled since it has GR as a dependency.

The message I see when installing packages is:

```
5 dependencies successfully precompiled in 40 seconds (201 already precompiled, 1 skipped during auto due to previous er
rors)
```

On the other hand when trying to force pre-compilation I see:

```
julia> Pkg.precompile()
Precompiling project...
  Progress [========================================>]  1/1
  ✗ GR_jll
0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 5 seconds (201 already precompiled)
```

This is very annoying and my modules remain uncompiled. What should I do to repair that situation?

Answer (score 3):

As of today `GR_jll` seems to be the only module that seems to require administrative rights on Windows to get installed.

1. Run your console as administrator
2. Start Julia and run the following script:

   ```
   using Pkg
   Pkg.build("GR_jll")
   Pkg.precompile()
   ```

I have seen other people claiming to have the same problem as I `1 skipped during auto due to previous errors` so hopefully this will be helpful for other Windows users.