# ERROR: could not load library "libGR.dll"

Tags: plot, julia

I am a complete beginner to Julia and have some experience with Python.

I want to do plotting in Julia but got this Error message, ERROR: could not load library "libGR.dll"

I have a simple program,

```
using Plots
x = range(0, 10, length=100)
y = sin.(x)
plot(x, y)
```

I have already downloaded the Plots package.

Comment: Please include your OS, Julia version info, and environment info (`] status`)

Comment: Occasionally there used to be some issues with the GR package installer and management of files. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314494/gr-jll-keeps-failing-to-precompile-where-using-julia-1-6-0-rc1-on-windows/66314495#66314495  However, without more details it is not possible to help